# Remove header value from the response

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have a laravel system and I am storing one of my response in a particular file like this :

```
$objFile = new Filesystem();
        $path = "files/FileName.php";
        $string = $this->getSlides();
        if ($objFile->exists($path))
        {
            $objFile->put($path,"",$lock = false);
            $objFile->put($path,$string,$lock = false);
            $objFile->getRequire($path);
        }
        else
            return getcwd() . "\n";
```

Now i get the contents using the following lines:

```
$objFile = new Filesystem();
        $path = "files/FileName.php";

        if ($objFile->exists($path))
        {
            return Response::json([$objFile->getRequire($path)],200);
        }
        else
            return getcwd() . "\n";
```

Now what's happening is that when I store the file on the server it adds some header like :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2016 05:38:08 GMT
```

followed by my stored file , so when I call the file on my frontend , I get the following error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0(…)
```

of course it expects from me a json value however i m giving it something that doesn't start like 1. Any idea how i can remove that on php level?

Comment: how you store json in .php file? it should use .json with content of valid json format, not using array

Comment: @h44f33z even if i use .json file still the header remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I made a bit of blunder while retrieving the result:
In the getSlides method i was using :

```
return Response::json([
      'Data' => $final_array
  ],200);
```

Now i replaced it with :

```
$final_array2 = array(
      'Data' => $final_array
      );
  return json_encode($final_array2);
```

Sorry because i didn't put this code and hence no one could have got any idea

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong method for getting file content.
`$objFile->getRequire($path)` - it will execute following code chunk: `return require $path;`. You have to use `$objFile->get($path)` to get file's content.

Comment: that gives me null

Comment: @AdityaSingh Are You sure that Your file contains something? I just tried myself and everything worked just fine. You can try my one-line code: `return Response::json((new Filesystem)->get(app_path('Http/routes.php')), 200);` (assuming You have routes.php file)

Comment: yea it worked but the header is in the content so the output is again the same

Comment: @AdityaSingh I am not sure what You really need, but try this: `return response()->download($pathToFile);`. I think You need that file download will start when You hit that url, is that right? Or You need that application return file content is JSON object?